# Objective-C Semaphore Issues?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, semaphore

I've got this code:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[self.skView.scene fadeOutWithDuration:FADE_SEC completion:^ {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
[self startGame];
```

And unfortunately, the semaphore is not being signaled. I have no idea why...

Here's the `fadeOutWithDuration:completion:` code:

```
- (void) fadeOutWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration completion:(void (^)(void))predicate {
    SKAction * action = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0 duration:duration];
    [self runAction:action completion:predicate];
}
```

I previously had `[self startGame]` in the completion block, but there appeared to be a memory leak occurring in this block of code, so I decided to use a semaphore instead to ensure that the block wasn't retaining anything. Any idea on why the semaphore isn't being signaled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the fade actually happen?

Comment: No. It did before I added the semaphore. I think what is happening is that the semaphore is blocking the main thread, which prevents the fadeOut method from completing and then calling the semaphore signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scene executes its per-frame processing on the main thread by registering an observer with the main thread's run loop. You're blocking the main thread by calling `dispatch_semaphore_wait` on it, so the run loop doesn't continue running and get to call the scene's observer.

The solution is to not block the main thread. Move `[self startGame]` back into the completion block, and fix the memory leak.

The standard pattern for avoiding a retain cycle (and ensuing memory leak) in a completion block looks like this:

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
[self.skView.scene fadeOutWithDuration:FADE_SEC completion:^ {
    MyClass *self = weakSelf;
    [self startGame];
}];
```

Replace `MyClass` with the actual class of `self`.

Comment: Yup, as I mentioned in my comment...semaphore blocked the main thread. Also, I tried using a weak reference before attempting the semaphore. That way wasn't working, thus the desperate semaphore attempt...